# Vision AI using OpenCV

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I know this may sound dumb, but last time, [I posted C++ code, similar to this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162913/color-guessing-code):

> This is just something to get me closer to actually doing a neural network. This code is supposed to learn colors from many many data images, and then recognize color using an algorithm that I made. Eventually, I want the program to make its own algorithm.

That was my prototype to the Python version. Why you ask? Because I am better in C++ so I prototyped it in C++, but I want the final version to be in Python so bringing it onto a Raspberry Pi would be easier.

The lower HSV target getting part is quite sketchy so hopefully someone can make it better. My goal is to make the fastest **PYTHON** program possible.

[Code and training data is on GitHub. Consider contributing directly to the repository.](https://github.com/DatHA3990/VisionAI_Py/tree/4b95c4a5b381962485bc4472148c49fff3b9c4b5)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os

SCALAR_SIZE = 3

COLOR_NAME = 0
COLOR_BGR = 1
COLOR_DIFFERENCE = 2
COLOR_ACCURACY = 3

DIR_TRAIN_DATA = "train_data"
DIR_TEST_DATA = "test_data"
DIR_SAVED_DATA = "saved_data"

DIR_NAME = "name"
FILE_NAME = "name.txt"

DIR_IMAGE = "images"

FILE_SAVED_HSV = "hsv_values.txt"

def nothing(something):
    pass

def get_bgr_difference(bgr):
    return [bgr[0] - bgr[1], bgr[1] - bgr[2], bgr[2] - bgr[0]]

def get_color(image, colors):
    difference = get_bgr_difference(np.average(np.average(image, axis=0), axis=0))
    accuracy = []
    for color in colors:
        accuracy.append(1 - (np.average(abs(np.subtract((color[COLOR_DIFFERENCE], difference)))) / 255))
    color_accuracy = max(accuracy)
    color_match = colors[accuracy.index(color_accuracy)]
    color_match[COLOR_ACCURACY] = color_accuracy
    return color_match

def get_trained_colors():
    color = []
    for train_data_folder in os.walk(DIR_TRAIN_DATA):
        for color_name in train_data_folder[1]:
            if color_name != DIR_NAME and color_name != DIR_IMAGE:
                location = DIR_TRAIN_DATA + '/' + color_name + '/'
                bgr = []
                for color_images in os.walk(location + '/' + DIR_IMAGE):
                    for image_file in color_images[2]:
                        bgr.append(
                            np.average(np.average(cv.imread(location + '/' + DIR_IMAGE + '/' + image_file, cv.IMREAD_COLOR), axis=0),
                                       axis=0))
                bgr = np.average(bgr, axis=0)
                color.append([open(location + DIR_NAME + '/' + FILE_NAME).read(), bgr, get_bgr_difference(bgr), 1])
    return color

def get_position_in_list(myList, v):
    for i, x in enumerate(myList):
        if v in x:
            return i, x.index(v)

def get_target_image_bgr(colors, image, target_color_name, tolerance):
    color = colors[get_position_in_list(colors, target_color_name)[0]][COLOR_BGR]
    image = cv.inRange(cv.blur(image, (15, 15)), np.subtract(color, tolerance), np.add(color, tolerance))
    return image

def get_target_image_hsv(image, tolerance):
    cv.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    image = cv.inRange(cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV), tolerance[0], tolerance[1])
    kernel = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)
    image = cv.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=1)
    cv.imshow("hsv", image)
    return image

def get_target_coordinate(image):
    x = cv.findContours(image, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
    y = []
    cnt = []
    for i in x:
        y.append(np.average(i, axis=0))
    cnt = np.average(y, axis=0)[0]
    return cnt

def draw_target(image, coordinates):
    cv.circle(image, (int(coordinates[0]), int(coordinates[1])), 5, (255, 0, 255), -1)
    cv.imshow("image", image)
    cv.waitKey(1)

def draw_trackbar_hsv():
    window_name = 'tracker'
    cv.namedWindow(window_name)
    for i in ['h', 's', 'v']:
        for j in range(2):
            cv.createTrackbar(i + str(j), 'tracker', 0, 255, nothing)

def get_trackbar():
    hsv = np.array([[0] * 3] * 2)
    hsv[0][0] = cv.getTrackbarPos('h0', 'tracker')
    hsv[1][0] = cv.getTrackbarPos('h1', 'tracker')
    hsv[0][1] = cv.getTrackbarPos('s0', 'tracker')
    hsv[1][1] = cv.getTrackbarPos('s1', 'tracker')
    hsv[0][2] = cv.getTrackbarPos('v0', 'tracker')
    hsv[1][2] = cv.getTrackbarPos('v1', 'tracker')
    return hsv

def set_trackbar():
    text_file = open(DIR_SAVED_DATA + '/' + FILE_SAVED_HSV, "r")
    hsv = text_file.read().split(',')
    text_file.close()
    hsv.remove('')
    hsv = [int(i) for i in hsv]
    cv.setTrackbarPos('h0', 'tracker', hsv[0])
    cv.setTrackbarPos('h1', 'tracker', hsv[3])
    cv.setTrackbarPos('s0', 'tracker', hsv[1])
    cv.setTrackbarPos('s1', 'tracker', hsv[4])
    cv.setTrackbarPos('v0', 'tracker', hsv[2])
    cv.setTrackbarPos('v1', 'tracker', hsv[5])

def save_trackbar_hsv(hsv):
    name = DIR_SAVED_DATA + '/' + FILE_SAVED_HSV
    open(name, "w").close()
    text_file = open(name, "w")
    for i in hsv:
        for j in i:
            text_file.write(str(j))
            text_file.write(',')
    text_file.close()

image = cv.imread(DIR_TEST_DATA + '/' + "boiler3.jpg", cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv.namedWindow("image")
cv.namedWindow("hsv")
draw_trackbar_hsv()
set_trackbar()
while True:
    hsv_val = get_trackbar()
    hsv_image = get_target_image_hsv(image, hsv_val)
    coordinate = get_target_coordinate(hsv_image)
    save_trackbar_hsv(hsv_val)
    draw_target(image, coordinate)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Not dumb at all, most welcome actually - and excellent title, too! I've included the description from the previous post to make it self-contained, feel free to [edit] to further expand on what's sketchy about the lower HSV target getting part =)

Comment: As much as I love Python, it's not the right tool for your goal: "My goal is to make the fastest program possible. Speed is important for me."

Comment: @Peilonrayz, I re-phrased the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a dictionary

The following function looks like it might get slow if it's called often:

```
def get_position_in_list(myList, v):
    for i, x in enumerate(myList):
        if v in x:
            return i, x.index(v)
```

If `colors` is a large list of lists (say 100 by 100), then searching through it one by one will give you a significant performance hit.

I'm not sure how often you plan to run `get_target_image_bgr`, but it's probably going to be often, especially if it'll be in a `while True` loop, similar to `get_target_image_hsv`.

In that case, when you create the 'colors' argument to `get_target_image_bgr`, use a dictionary instead of a list of lists:

Initializing the dictionary:

```
colors = {}
for i,_ in enumerate(myList):
    for j, v in enumerate(myList[i]):
        colors[v] = (i, j)
```

Looking up values in the dictionary:

```
colors[v]
```

This will return the same co-ordinates as your `get_position_in_list` function, but each lookup takes \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ instead of \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$.

(Note: I have assumed `v` is unique. If not, the dictionary as I have it will return the last match, while your `get_position_in_list` function returns the first match.)

### Reduce writes to file

With new SSDs getting up to 4GB/s write, this old axiom may not be as important as it once was. Still, I think you should change up your `save_trackbar_hsv`, you will probably notice a big performance difference.

Currently, you are writing a two-dimensional array to file with every iteration of the `while True` loop. Not only that, but you are also making a separate call to `write` for every data value.

Your `save_trackbar_hsv` should make only one call to `write`, writing all data values in one go, with appropriate delimiters:

```
def save_trackbar_hsv(hsv):
    name = DIR_SAVED_DATA + '/' + FILE_SAVED_HSV
    open(name, "w").close()
    text_file = open(name, "w")
    between_values_delimiter = " "
    between_lines_delimiter = ","
    file_data = []

    for i in hsv:
        file_line = []
        for j in i:
            file_line.append(str(j))
        file_data.append(between_values_delimiter.join(file_line))
    text_file.write(between_lines_delimiter.join(file_data))
```

You may also wish to store file data for multiple calls to `save_trackbar_hsv` in a list, and only write on perhaps each 100th call to the funcion.

On the positive side: good use of numpy, opencv and os.walk.

Lastly, sometimes you may hear the attitude that any program written in C++ is by default faster than any program written in Python. That is certainly not true.

Looks OK overall, and a great effort! Congrats for branching out  to Python.

Comment: I would recommend using `with open(...)` to ensure it is properly closed. (Note that this makes re-using the `save_trackbar_hsv` function slightly harder when you want to only write every hundreth entry, but still).